# Vaadin Treetable - Custom sort to skip parent row

Tags: java, sorting, parent, vaadin, treetable

In my Vaadin 7 project, I need to ignore the parent nodes(rows) of a treetable while sorting. I am able to customize the sort using ItemSort, but I don't know how to skip the parent nodes!

FYI: I am able to identify my parent node with its ItemId.

****Update**********

I'm using a Hierarchical Container, and my Tree is similar to this:

```
Name            Nos             salary
+ Male(Node 1)  5               $12000
  + Young       3               $6000
    A           1               $3000
    B           1               $1000
    c           1               $2000
  + Old         2               $6000
    A           1               $3000
    B           1               $3000
+ Female(Node 2)5               $13000
  + Young       3               $5000
    A           1               $2000
    B           1               $1000
    c           1               $2000
  + Old         2               $8000
    A           1               $5000
    B           1               $3000
```

The problem is when I sort the salary column it includes the summation of each person's salary on "Male, young & old", "Female, young & old" rows and adjusts the position of "Male, Female" and "Young, old" categories.

I just want to skip the parent nodes in my custom sort. It should only the children nodes. In simple words. All the parent nodes should be fixed, and only the child nodes have to be sorted.

**Updated USECASE**

Two elements having same parents and those two elements has no child nodes
then I used DefaultItemSorter.compare(). And I ignored all other use cases.

Comment: Someone please answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a related Problem, with special tree table sorting. I ended up writing my own Container and Comperator implementation.

Your question depends on the container you are using, since the sorting is done by the the underlying container and not the table. By default TreeTable uses the HierarchicalContainer implementation, where you could use your own ItemSorter implementation. You could extend DefaultItemSorter and distinguish different cases when comparing two elements:

- Two leaf elements having the same parent: 

  use DefaultItemSorter.compare()
- Two parent elements having the same parent (also null):

  return the value to keep the order you want
- An element to one in its path to the root:

  return a value so the deeper element is after the higher.
- Two elements **not** having the same parent:

  In both paths go up the tree until you find the depth where the next parents are the same and compare these two elements. Start with the deeper element and go up until you are on the same level as the other.

I hope i didn't forget a case. Anyway I advise you to write several unit tests to be sure your ItemSorter does the right thing in all the cases.

If you know that your tree has special characteristics, like the maximal depth is two, you might simplify the ItemSorter. I couldn't see that from your question. Please add more details next time.

Comment: Hey Raffael, I have updated my Question. Kindly check it out. It may help you to understand my problem.

Comment: And I had override the DefaultItemSorter in my code. In compare(o1, o2), what can I do with that o1 and o2. they are just objects right. How to find whether they have same parents or not. A little code will help me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: o1 and o2 are the itemIds of the the elements to compere. see the compare function here: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/data/util/DefaultItemSorter.java?source=cc

Comment: Thanks raffael.. I will check it out.

Comment: Heh Raffael check my Updated UseCase.. It seems like working fine.. Will it take care of all the use cases that you mentioned..

Comment: It worked for me man.. Thank you..But, you please check the case I have updated.. I have used that case alone in my code.

Comment: Glad it worked. Thats what i have meant with "leaf elements". Elements not having a child element

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks Rafael... And did you notice that compareTo() is used to compare two strings in DefaultItemSorter.. And It won't handle Alphanumeric values; that results in improper sort.. I faced that issue while sort and fixed it by using Alphanumeric comparison.. Check this https://vaadin.com/old-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/3642788